# How to enable Flash to HTMLUnit?

Tags: java, flash, htmlunit

I'm trying to grab html contents by HTMLUnit. Everything went nice, but couldn't get Flash contents those are visible as `<img>` where its actually in `<object>`, i have

```
   webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
   webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true);
   webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
```

In SO some places i found [someone](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/mailman/message/26768070/) saying HTMLUnit won't support Flash, but those answers seems old, so am raising this question. Someone please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Check if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876147/scraping-flash-using-htmlunit-or-other-java-tool

Comment: thanks @AKS i have seen that, but some another place i have seen that we can do some tricks like showing that "flash payer is enabled but outdated" so that it will be detected htmlunit as flash enabled browser. Some others wrote their own "browser version" for htmlunit enabling flash palyer. Want to know how to do such tricks atleast.

Comment: see [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/691/?page=1) patch

Comment: see [this](http://osdir.com/ml/java-htmlunit-general/2009-09/msg00034.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found it with the [help](http://worldhousefinder.com/?p=42435#comment-6800)
for this i have downgrade my HTMLUnit version from 2.15 to 2.13 as in 2.15 `BrowserVersionFeatures.JS_FRAME_RESOLVE_URL_WITH_PARENT_WINDOW` seems deprecated and don't know what feature replaced here.

```
   private static BrowserVersion firefox17WithUptoDateFlash = new BrowserVersion(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getApplicationName(),        BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getApplicationVersion(),        BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getUserAgent(),        BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getBrowserVersionNumeric(),new BrowserVersionFeatures[]{
    BrowserVersionFeatures.JS_FRAME_RESOLVE_URL_WITH_PARENT_WINDOW,
    BrowserVersionFeatures.STYLESHEET_HREF_EXPANDURL,
    BrowserVersionFeatures.STYLESHEET_HREF_STYLE_NULL
});
static {
    PluginConfiguration plugin1 = new PluginConfiguration(
            "Shockwave Flash",
            "Shockwave Flash 11.4 r402",
            "NPSWF32_11_4_402_287.dll");
    plugin1.getMimeTypes().add(new PluginConfiguration.MimeType(
            "application/x-shockwave-flash", 
            "Adobe Flash movie",
            "swf"));
    firefox17WithUptoDateFlash.getPlugins().add(plugin1);
}
   final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(firefox17WithUptoDateFlash);
```

Here newly written browser instance will give support to htmlunit to act as flash enabled GUI-less browser